# Node Quickpay authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to use [Node quickpay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick-pay)

However their documentation is not that "easy" to understand and i am kind of stuck with autentication.

I have my `API token` and i have followed the following SO question:

[QuickPay node.js REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428834/quickpay-node-js-rest-api)

To make the following:

```
    var quickPay = require("quick-pay");
module.exports = function (router, mongoose) {
    var token = "myToken";
    var version = {
        "Accept-Version": "v10",
        "Authorization": "your basic authentication"};

    var transaction_id = {};

    router.route('/api/payment')
        .put(function (req, res) {
            processCreatePayment(req, res);
        });

    function processCreatePayment(req, res) {
        var random_order_id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

        var parameters = {
            "currency": "INR",
            "order_id": random_order_id
        };
        quickPay.post("payments/", version, parameters)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                res.send(result);
                transaction_id = result.id;
                console.log(transaction_id);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {

                console.log(err.response);
                res.send(err.response);

            });
    }


    return router;
};
```

However im not quite sure what the: `"Authorization": "your basic authentication"` should be.

i hope someone can help me out.

Please note i have already attempted:

```
    var version = {
    "Accept-Version": "v10",
    "Authorization": "Basic "+token
};
```

But with out luck

All i get is `invalid Basic Auth`

Answer (score 2):

In order to use basic auth with token please try to add ':' before api key. So use:

```
"Authorization": ":" + apiKey
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe @maciej-dzikowicki is right but I just want to expand on his answer because this thing robbed me of far too much time.

The **tr;tl** is that [basic auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) requires a colon separated, base64 encoded string prefixed with `Basic`. In Quickpays case there's no username so the `Authorization` header is just your API key prefixed with a colon that is base64 encoded.

**In your case @marc-rasmussen** [Node Quickpay](https://github.com/Rainnwind/quick-pay/blob/master/index.js#L13) does this for you so you just need to provide your `API_KEY` to the factory function returned by the library.

Also so if anyone struggled (like me) to find their `API_KEY` here are the steps to find your it.

1. Navigate to the user's section of your Quickpay account https://manage.quickpay.net. Either select a user or "Create System User".

[image]

2. Select a user and ensure the correct permissions are set to access the API endpoints you require.

[image]

3. Click "See API Key" to get your API key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but follows the documentation. The header infos / basic auth should be set to a proper default (e.g. `"v10"`) when not set.

```
// Initialize quickPay with your API key    
var quickPay = require("quick-pay")(YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE);

module.exports = function (router, mongoose) {

    var transaction_id = {};

    router.route('/api/payment')
        .put(function (req, res) {
            processCreatePayment(req, res);
        });

    function processCreatePayment(req, res) {
        var random_order_id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);

        var parameters = {
            "currency": "INR",
            "order_id": random_order_id
        };
        quickPay.post("payments/", null, parameters)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                res.send(result);
                transaction_id = result.id;
                console.log(transaction_id);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {

                console.log(err.response);
                res.send(err.response);

            });
    }


    return router;
};
```